# WinSCP putting multiple files on SFTP site

Tags: script, sftp, winscp, wildcards

With WinSCP 5.2 I wanted to put multiple files with a file extension `.pgp` on an SFTP site. When I tested my original command line (see below) and it only placed the first `*.pgp` alphabetical file (`D:\a.csv.pgp`) on the SFTP site. I tried specifying `*.PGP` and `*.pgp` without any changes - only one file (`D:\a.csv.pgp`) would be copied each time. I got it to work for all files only if I specified a put command for each `.pgp` file. Any ideas on how to put all `*.pgp` on the SFTP site?

Original Command Line - Does Not Work
`d:\winscp\winscp /command "option echo off" "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open sftp" "put D:\*.pgp" "close" "exit"`

Works
`d:\winscp\winscp /command "option echo off" "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open sftp" "put D:\a.csv.pgp" "put D:\b.csv.pgp" "put D:\c.csv.pgp" "put D:\d.csv.pgp" "put D:\e.csv.pgp" "put D:\f.csv.pgp" "put D:\g.csv.pgp" "put D:\h.csv.pgp" "put D:\i.csv.pgp" "close" "exit"`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using SFTP mode rather than SCP mode

<strike>Try `mput *.pgp` (a guess based on FTP commands)</strike>

The [manual](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) says wildcards should work

> `put <file> [ [ <file2> ... ] <directory>/[ <newname> ] ]`
>   If only one parameter is specified uploads the file to remote working directory. If more parameters are specified, all except the last one specify set of files to upload. The last parameter specifies target remote directory and optionally operation mask to store file(s) under different name. Destination directory must end with slash. Filename can be replaced with Windows wildcard1) to select multiple files. To upload more files to current working directory use ./ as the last parameter.

…

> `put *.html *.png /home/martin/backup/*.bak`

You MUST put the target directory as the last item in the quoted command.

`d:\winscp\winscp /command "option echo off" "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open sftp" "put D:\*.pgp ""C:\Documents and Settings\newtowinscp\Documents\Backups""" "close" "exit"`

Comment: As OP has only single parameter in his `put D:\*.pgp` command, it's not necessary to add the target directory as the last parameter. Moreover in your example, you use a Windows path as a target directory, what won't work (even if the server is Windows server, with SFTP, paths have to use forward slash as separators).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from a script, you can just create a loop. You would take all of the *.pgp files and iterate through the list. You would actually upload the files individually; I don't believe that SFTP/SCP at the protocol level moves multiple files at once anyway, so I don't think this should affect performance, it would probably make error handling easier as well.

I believe there is a way to do this with the pure native command line, but in my backup scripts (I do the inverse, I pull files down from my SFTP site) I use this program (forfiles) from Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx . I will let you read through the examples there on how to use it most effectively for your needs. Basically, you will use a wildcard for filename and then run your upload command for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your first command (with `put D:\*.pgp`).

As you claim that only a single file is uploaded, it's likely because some error occurs, what prevent the script from continuing with other files. It must be an error in operation that following the actual upload (as that succeeds), such as updating uploaded file timestamp or permissions.

Such as this error:  [Upload of file .. was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp. If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_preserve_time_perm).

You should clearly see, what is actually wrong in the script output or session log file.